# Spring - Can't display records from DB in HTML

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

Could you please take a look why i can't display any data from mySQL data base in my html page?

My hibernate query returning all values from the database.

**employee.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Spring Boot MVC Security using Thymeleaf</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h3>User Employess Details</h3>
<div>
    Logged in user: <b th:inline="text"  class="user"> [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]] </b>
    <form th:action="@{/app-logout}" method="POST">
         <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
    </form>
</div> <br/>     
<table>
<tr th:each="employee : ${Employess}">
    <td th:text="${employee.employee_id}">Id</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.first_name}">First Name</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.last_name}">Last Name</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.full_name}">Full Name</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.email_address}">Email</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.phone_number}">Phone Number</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.account_type}">Account Type</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.account_status}">Account Status</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.valid_from}">Valid from</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.valid_until}">Valid until</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.is_manager}">Is Manager?</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.street}">Street</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.home_nbr}">Home Number</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.city}">City</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.state}">State</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.post_code}">Post Code</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.birth_day}">Birth Day</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.branch}">Branch</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.department}">Department</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.position}">Position</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.position_desc}">Position Description</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**EmployeeController**

```
package com.project.controller;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.project.entity.Employee;
import com.project.service.EmployeeService;

@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.*"})
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

@Resource(name = "employeeService")
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired(required=true)
@Qualifier(value="employeeService")
public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService ps){
    this.employeeService = ps;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/employess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listEmployess(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
    model.addAttribute("listEmployess", this.employeeService.getAllEmployees());
    return "employee";
}

//For add and update person both
@RequestMapping(value= "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee p){

    if(p.getEmployeeID() == 0){
        //new person, add it
        this.employeeService.addEmployee(p);
    }else{
        //existing person, call update
        this.employeeService.updateEmployee(p);
    }

    return "redirect:/employess";

}

@RequestMapping("/remove/{employee_id}")
public String removeEmployee(@PathVariable("employee_id") int employee_id){

    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(employee_id);
    return "redirect:/employess";
}

@RequestMapping("/edit/{employee_id}")
public String editEmployee(@PathVariable("employee_id") int employee_id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("employee", this.employeeService.getEmployee(employee_id));
    model.addAttribute("listEmployess", this.employeeService.getAllEmployees());
    return "employee";
}

}
```

**Employee entity configuration:**

```
package com.project.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.*"})
@Entity
@Table(name="TEMPLOYEE", schema= "mydb")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int employee_id;  
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String first_name;
@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String last_name;
@Column(name="FULL_NAME")
    private String full_name;
@Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")   
    private String email_address;
@Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER")    
    private String phone_number;
@Column(name="ACCOUNT_TYPE")    
    private String account_type;
@Column(name="ACCOUNT_STATUS")  
    private String account_status;
@Column(name="VALID_FROM")  
    private String valid_from;
@Column(name="VALID_UNTIL") 
    private String valid_until;
@Column(name="IS_MANAGER")  
    private String is_manager;
@Column(name="STREET")  
    private String street;
@Column(name="HOME_NBR")    
    private String home_nbr;
@Column(name="CITY")    
    private String city;
@Column(name="STATE")   
    private String state;
@Column(name="POST_CODE")   
    private String post_code;
@Column(name="BIRTH_DAY")   
    private String birth_day;
@Column(name="BRANCH")  
    private String branch;
@Column(name="DEPARTMENT")  
    private String department;
@Column(name="POSITION")    
    private String position;
@Column(name="POSITION_DESC")   
    private String position_desc;

public int getEmployeeID() {
    return employee_id;
}
public void SetEmployeeID(int employee_id) {
    this.employee_id = employee_id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return first_name;
}
public void SetFirstName(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return last_name;
}
public void SetLastName(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}
public String getFullName() {
    return full_name;
}
public void SetFullName(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
}
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return email_address;
}
public void SetEmailAddress(String email_address) {
    this.email_address = email_address;
}
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phone_number;
}
public void SetPhoneNumber(String phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}
public String getAccountType() {
    return account_type;
}
public void SetAccountType(String account_type) {
    this.account_type = account_type;
}
public String getValidFrom() {
    return valid_from;
}
public void SetValidFrom(String valid_from) {
    this.valid_from = valid_from;
}
public String getValidUntil() {
    return valid_until;
}
public void SetValidUntil(String valid_until) {
    this.valid_until = valid_until;
}
public String getIsManager() {
    return is_manager;
}
public void SetIsManager(String is_manager) {
    this.is_manager = is_manager;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void SetStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getHomeNbr() {
    return home_nbr;
}
public void SetHomeNbr(String home_nbr) {
    this.home_nbr = home_nbr;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void SetCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void SetState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getPostCode() {
    return post_code;
}
public void SetPostCode(String post_code) {
    this.post_code = post_code;
}
public String getBirthDay() {
    return birth_day;
}
public void SetBirthDay(String birth_day) {
    this.birth_day = birth_day;
}
public String getBranch() {
    return branch;
}
public void SetBranch(String branch) {
    this.branch = branch;
}
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void SetDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}
public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public void SetPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}
public String getPositionDesc() {
    return position_desc;
}
public void SetPositionDesc(String position_desc) {
    this.position_desc = position_desc;
}
}
```

**EmployeeDAO:**

```
package com.project.dao;

import java.util.List;
import com.project.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeDAO {

public Employee addEmployee(Employee employee);

public List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

public void deleteEmployee(int employee_id);

public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee);

public Employee getEmployee(int  employee_id);
}
```

An my **Service** configuration:

```
package com.project.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.project.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.project.entity.Employee;

@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

 @Autowired(required=true)
 private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

 @Transactional
 public Employee addEmployee(Employee employee) {

 System.out.println("Employee service create invoked:"+employee.getEmployeeID());
 employee = employeeDAO.addEmployee(employee);
 return employee;
 }
 @Transactional
 public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {

 System.out.println("Employee Service Update invoked:"+employee.getEmployeeID());
 employee = employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);
 return employee;
 }

 public Employee getEmployee(int employee_id) {
 return employeeDAO.getEmployee(employee_id);
 }

 public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
 return employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
 }
 @Transactional
 public void deleteEmployee(int employee_id) {
employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(employee_id);
 }


}
```

I really don't have any idea what could be wrong here. I've tried different configurations in my html file but unfortunatelly with no positive results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the right variable's name. In your controller, you are adding an attribute called `listEmployees`, while in your html, you are iterating through an variable called `Employees`. You need to change your code for the following one.

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${listEmployess}">
    <td th:text="${employee.employee_id}">Id</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.first_name}">First Name</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.last_name}">Last Name</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.full_name}">Full Name</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.email_address}">Email</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.phone_number}">Phone Number</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.account_type}">Account Type</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.account_status}">Account Status</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.valid_from}">Valid from</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.valid_until}">Valid until</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.is_manager}">Is Manager?</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.street}">Street</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.home_nbr}">Home Number</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.city}">City</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.state}">State</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.post_code}">Post Code</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.birth_day}">Birth Day</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.branch}">Branch</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.department}">Department</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.position}">Position</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.position_desc}">Position Description</td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've changed this and now received following info from logs: 
EL1008E: Property or field 'employee_id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.project.entity.Employee' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: Can you check what happens if you remove <td th:text="${employee.employee_id}">Id</td>? Does the rest of the information gets displayed?

Comment: So, the next value cannot be found on object too. EL1008E: Property or field 'first_name' cannot be found on object of type 'com.project.entity.Employee' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: Hi, I figured out the reason for this error. I had to change the column declaration in my entity class to public. And your solution solved the issue. :). For now, i can see that two records are listed on my HTML page but page can't retrieve correct values. I mean - for the first name field I've ${employee.first_name} value instead of : Michal.

Comment: Excellent! Good to know you were capable of solving the issue and that I was of help. Now, that last issue with the first_name does seem odd. Could it be that something is missing with the `th:value` tag?

Comment: Yes, you're right :D I have used wrong mapping (After some modification from my side). Just copied mapping from your post and all working fine. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)